# How to generate entity classes from nhibernate mapping files during runtime

Tags: c#, nhibernate, code-generation

i need some help with c# and nhibernate.
I'm working on a project that requires the entity classes to be generated from hbm files at runtime.
I get the mapping files from a service, and then need to generate the classes dynamicaly and configure nhibernate to use them.

The problem is that i'm new to nhibernate and not much of a pro in c#, so me writing the piece of code that achieves this is very error-prone.

I was wondering if you know of any open source software that i could use.
Worst case scenario (if can't find anything that even remotely resembles what i need), do you guys have some advice on where should i start? Maybe some links ?

Thanks, Denis.

Comment: How will these classes be used once you generate them?

Comment: i hope to use them to retrieve data from the database using a generic repository and reflection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a fairly non-trivial task.  There's the [hbm2net](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/tags/hbm2net/default.aspx) project you could take a look at, but it's still in alpha and I don't know if it would easily let you do it at runtime.

You should also take a look at the [NHibernate Workbench](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2010/05/19/nhibernate-workbench.aspx) project, it seems to be doing something similar to what you're doing.