# Generating table class for postgres

Tags: class, postgresql, entity

I have a postgres database and I want to generate the entity class of a table. I need this in order to connect to the database without using something like :

```
NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT * FROM TABLE1", conn);
```

How can I obtain the class?
Can you provide some detailed steps? I can't seem to find this anywhere.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entity classes are usually hand-written, or are generated from a schema then hand-tweaked. In the Java world many tools like NetBeans and Eclipse can help, but things seem much less mature in the C#/.NET world if you're not using Microsoft databases and Microsoft query tools.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2892487/398670) refers to a few useful tools, and a quick search also found the [NHibernate entity generator](http://www.devart.com/entitydeveloper/nhibernate-entity-generator.html), which seems to be part of a tool with support for Entity Framework and LINQ too.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on a language but yes - you can do something like this in Java or Python using Object Relational tools such as SQLAlchemy, Hybernate, iBatis, etc.

They can generate schema for you, can populate data based on the definitions of objects.